# how to get validated the associated attributes? rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am using rails4. I have a model, lets say human. Human has nested model Man. Man has attributes Name, Address, Number. I am trying to make an api in which i am not able to validate associated attributes. I was able to validate the man by using validates_associated, But my model is getting saved without validating the attributes name address and number. How can I validate their presence or mumericalitty if I am saving it from its parent controller? In humans controller I am saving Man like this

```
if @human.save
  @man = @human.man.build
  @man.name = params[:man][:name]
  @man.address = params[:man][:address]
  @man.number = params[:man][:number]
  @man.save
```

How to validate these attributes before saving? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `valid?` method. It will trigger validations defined in model and return `true` or `false`.

```
if @man.valid?
  @man.save
else
 #do smth else
```

Further reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#valid-questionmark-and-invalid-questionmark

Answer (score 1):

usually, validations are placed in each respective model.

if human `accepts_nested_attributes_for` man, placing a validation in man for the presence of those attributes should prevent you from saving both human and man during the building and saving process

Comment: but its saving without giving me a validation error evan after including accepts_nested_attributes_for also